# how can i pass value from child to parent component in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

I need to get data from child component. My child component has form which is in popu. How can i pass full details to parent component.
my parent component ts file is

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-vehicle-relocate',
    templateUrl: './vehicle-relocate.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./vehicle-relocate.component.css'],
})
export class VehicleRelocateComponent implements OnInit {

    lat: number = 11.074529;
    lng: number = 78.003917;
    zoom: number = 14;

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open();
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}
```

My child component is in parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-relocate-form',
  templateUrl: './relocate-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./relocate-form.component.css']
})
export class RelocateFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<RelocateFormComponent>) {}
  @Input() title:string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: will it help? https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/dialog/dialog-demo.ts

Comment: Which one is a child component?

Comment: second one is child component

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova i can seen it but my problem is can't use more than one component in ts file

Comment: I want to pass full html template from child to parent popup element

Comment: Template? You can get TemplateRef of child component using VieChild as as TemplateRef and pass it to the parent as shown in demo-app. TemplateRef is a regular object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `Output` to your child component.
For example: `@Output() notifySubmit : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()`(you can put whatever type you want if you don't want 'any').

Then when you're submitting the form in your child component, you have to notify the parent with the `Output`:

```
this.notifySubmit.emit(myValues)
```

Now you have to receive the event in the parent component. When you call your `RelocateFormComponent` from `VehicleRelocateComponent` you need to pass a function to the `Output`.

```
<app-relocate-form (notifySubmit)="myFunction($event)" ... ></app-relocate-form>
```

`myFunction($event)`has to be in the parent component. The `$event` parameter equals to what you sent with `this.notifySubmit.emit(myValues)`.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for route parameters?